# Does NGEN'ing a .NET application help protect it from reverse engineering? If not when would I use it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compiler-construction, ngen

If Ngen doesn't protect my application, when would I reasonably expect to use this application in my career?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeffrey Richter wrote a great piece in his book, I don't know if the third release has it, but here is a great piece he [wrote](http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/.NET/net_general/toolsand3rdparty/print.php/c4651/) in 2002 about Ngen'ing which is still relevant.

Highlights:

> Meanwhile, there are several potential
> problems with respect to NGen'd files:
>
> - No Intellectual Property Protection. Many people believe that
>   it might be possible to ship NGend
>   files without shipping the files
>   containing the original IL code
>   thereby keeping their intellectual
>   property a secret. Unfortunately, this
>   is not possible. At runtime, the CLR
>   requires access to the assemblys
>   metadata and the NGend files do not
>   contain the metadata.
> - NGend Files Can Get Out-Of-Sync. When the CLR loads an
>   NGen'd file it compares a number of
>   attributes about the
>   previously-compile code and the
>   current execution environment. If any
>   of the attributes don't match then the
>   NGen'd file cannot be used and the
>   normal JIT compiler process is used
>   instead.
> - Poor Administration. NGen'd file are not automatically deleted when an
>   assembly is uninstalled adversely
>   affecting the .NET Frameworks easy
>   administration and XCOPY deployment
>   story.
> - Inferior Load-Time Performance (Rebasing). When Windows loads an
>   NGend file, it checks to see if the
>   file loads at its preferred base
>   address. If the file cant load at its
>   preferred base address, then Windows
>   relocates the file, fixing-up all of
>   the memory address references. This is
>   extremely time consuming because
>   Windows must load the entire file into
>   memory and modify various bytes within
>   the file. For more information about
>   rebasing please see my book:
>   Programming Applications for Microsoft
>   Windows, 4th Edition (Microsoft
>   Press).
>
> #### Inferior Execution-Time Performance.
>
> When compiling code, NGen cant make as many assumptions about the execution environment as the JIT compiler can. This causes NGen.exe to produce code with a number of memory-reference indirections that aren't necessary for JIT compiled code

Comment: There should be no 'admin' issues. I have have not even had an NGEN'ed assembly with the same version cause ill effects (because it wont load if the hash dont match).

Comment: I just posted a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591699/how-do-i-prevent-ngen-from-rebasing-my-code-negatively-affecting-performance

Answer (score 1):

NGen is only for compiling the IL for performance increases.  You would want to look into code obfuscation for protecting the app from reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Loading speed is all it is really useful for. That said, it can make up to a 2000% (yes that is correct) improvement.

Edit:

Please note that JIT'ed code normally tends to be faster than NGEN'ed code.

Comment: Can I NGEN ASP.NET?  When would I need to re-run NGEN?

Comment: for ASP.NET you would rather use precompilation.

Comment: You could, if you know you know your application will not change frequently. Also you would have to use the `aspnet_compiler` to make sure all your 'front end' code gets compiled into assemblies as well.

Comment: Is this related to the ASP Warmup tool by Microsoft? I haven't gone too deep into it.